# Rails ERb best practices (<% %> vs <% -%> vs <%- -%>)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, evaluate

What is the recommended use of ERb in Rails when it comes to `<% %>` (evaluate Ruby code), `<% -%>` (evaluate Ruby code, suppress the trailing newline) and `<%- -%>` (evaluate Ruby code, suppress the trailing newline and leading space)? It seems like `<%- -%>` would make the output HTML look nicest, but `<% %>` seems to be mostly what I see.

Comment: IMHO, it doesn't really matter how "nice" the HTML looks as long as there is some visible indented structure to the generated HTML, I don't bother with supressing newlines etc.

Comment: I think <% %> and <% -%> are synonymous in rails 3 (no trailing newline)

Comment: I think you're [shaving yaks](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/gsb/old-archive/gsb-archive/gsb2000-02-11.html). There are many things to worry about when coding but whether your emitted HTML looks good is not real high on the list of things to do that make a big difference. But, don't feel bad, because you're in good company. We all do it.

Comment: @Greg +1 to your comment for teaching me the term "yak shaving".

Comment: LOL. Yep. It's kind of disturbing to learn there's a term for it. I always thought it was called procrastinating. Now go watch the Ren and Stimpy show to find the episode. :-)

Comment: Don't underestimate the effect of clean, readable and therefore easier to debug code on developer's need for elegance. In my opinion, the result of your yak shaving might be a prime motivator for some people maintaining your website. Then again, there are surely more effective ways to make HTML more readable than manually through ERB tweaking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a personal preference. I use <% %> when I'm writing a loop or a block, because I want new lines there. I use <% -%> in rare cases of variable assignment. And I never use <%- -%> because that's one option too many.

Comment: `<%- if foo? ->` is just what you want in a rails generator template

Answer (score 7):

I just read in http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/ERB.html that you can even use a single percent sign for oneliners (if there is nothing else on that line)

Example from the docs:

```
<%# ignore numerous minor requests -- focus on priorities %>
% priorities.each do |priority|
  * <%= priority %>
% end
```

aaaalmost like HAML, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the trailing hyphen `-%>` works any more; I just got an error trying to use it in Ruby 2.6.6. However, @onetom's suggestion of using just a percent `%` for an entire line of code works, it outputs nothing, and doesn't keep the unwanted newline at the end.

Examples:

---

Trailing hyphen

```
line1
<%- sought = 'pattern' -%>
line3
```

Error message:

```
file.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ';' (SyntaxError)
; - sought = 'pattern' -; _erbout.<< "\n".freeze
```

---

No trailing hyphen:

```
line1
<%- sought = 'pattern' %>
line3
```

Output:

```
line1

line3
```

---

Percent only:

```
line1
% sought = 'pattern'
line3
```

Output:

```
line1
line3
```